# How to use 'replace' to remove spaces in data

Tags: mysql, replace

I have a query below by using of 'MySQL'

```
Select distinct IPC_CLASS_SYMBOL as IPC, count(distinct appln_id) as PATENT_COUNT
From OOO
Where replace(IPC_CLASS_SYMBOL,' ','') in ('G08G|G01W|G01S17/86|G01S15/86|G01S17/894|G01S17/88|G01S17/00')
group by IPC
order by IPC;
```

I can see only 'title' like below after I run the mysql.

```
IPC PATENT_COUNT
```

Comment: Please share sample data and desired results. We can't divine what your data looks like and what you want to do with it from your broken sql.

Comment: (1) GROUP BY and DISTINCT makes no sense together.  Remove the last one. (2) `WHERE value IN ('CSV string')` won't act as you need, use INSTR or LOCATE or FIND_IN_SET function.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.